# Azure Logic app - Condition action error 'The provided types object and object are not compatible'

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm attempting to move an email to a particular inbox based on the source. I have pulled the store out and have stored it in an Azure sql table. I also then have another table with my all my inboxes.

I want to do a condition that say, if my email subject contains an inbox stored in my inboxes table, move the email to that inbox, else do nothing.

I'm new to Azure so I'm still trying to figure out the possibilities and am currently getting the error that is below.

[image]

My condition action is below:
[image]
Here I am taking each InboxName(value-item) stored in my Inboxes table and trying to find a match within my body which contains all my email data.

I can't make sense of this error though, any ideas?

I think I should specify that I want to take the output of my function which is my email content and check it for an InboxName in my Inboxes table.

[image]

Comment: I think you have two actions, one is `Get row (V2)`, the other is `Get rows (V2)`, you only need to specify different tables in these two actions, and then use the expression I gave in `Condition` .

Comment: I can't seem to use the `Get row (V2)`, my table doesn't appear in the dropdown but does for `Get rows (V2)`. I have a function that outputs my email body as json, is there no way to check this json against the InboxNames from our `Get row(V2)`

Comment: So the 2nd expression would be right but the first I don't want to read a table for a value that i already have in the logic app at that point.

Comment: How did you get the `Body` in `condition`, after understanding, you can also use similar expressions to make your condition action correct.

Comment: That was my mistake for having the Body like that, it should be my function output. I've updated the question

Comment: Anyway, `condition`action cannot use object as a parameter, you can try String(body)? If it still doesn't work, you can only use an expression to make it accurate to a parameter in object.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I've solved it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Body` and `Value-item` are data of type Object. If you need to perform a `Conditon` action, you need to get the value of a specific column in the table.

[image]

You can refer to the following expression:

```
body('Get_row_(V2)')?['<your- column-name>']

items('For_each')?['<your-column-name>']
```